# How do I insert multiple rows inside a row on material ui

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm trying to add multiple rows inside a row of my table
See it here:

[image]

And I don't know why my 4 last cells are into the TableHead "Langues".

Here's my code :

```
<Paper className={classes.root}>
            <Table className={classes.table}>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell numeric>id</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Actif</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Payant</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Langues</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Noms</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Image univers débloqué</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Image univers bloqué</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
              {
                this.state.universes.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow key={i}>
                    <TableCell numeric>{item.id}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{item.active?"Oui":"Non"}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{item.free?"Non":"Oui"}</TableCell>
                        {
                          item.Langs.map((item, y) => {
                            return (
                              <TableRow key={y}>
                                <TableCell>{item.lang}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell><img height="50" src={item.activeImage}/></TableCell>
                                <TableCell><img height="50" src={item.disabledImage}/></TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            )
                          })
                        }
                    </TableRow>
                  )
                })
              }
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
```

Does someone can help me ?

Comment: it's normal because you create a new table row on TableCell Langues. You must merge cells explicitly with <TableRowColumn colSpan={4}>

Comment: <TableRowColumn> don't exist on the last release of Material UI...

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. Use if...else statement to return empty table cell for the cells you want to take up the whole column. Not the perfect solution still.

```
      <TableBody>
        {orders.map(({ info, items }) => {
            return items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={index}>
                  {index === 0 ? (
                    <Fragment>
                      <TableCell>{info.id}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{info.user}</TableCell>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <Fragment>
                      <TableCell>{}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{}</TableCell>
                    </Fragment>
                  )}

                  <TableCell>{item.sth}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{item.else}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            });
          })}
      </TableBody>
```